# Checking if all questions were answered with javascript

Tags: javascript, performance, beginner, validation, quiz

I made a quiz project and I made a code to see if all the questions were answered, using JavaScript.

It works, but its way more exhaustive than I wanted it to be. I first check every single option from each question and separate it, then I use a function to see if 
the question was answered (i.e. `allfalse()`), then put all returns from each question on a list, then after that I check this list with another function(i.e. `alltrue()`), to see if all questions were answered or not.

Its a very exhaustive method and I want to improve the readability and more importantly the performance, can somebody help me?(I was forbidden to use required from HTML, which would make it much easier)

Sorry for documentation in portuguese, but I think I explained well already.

```js
// Põe o ID das respostas certas em uma lista, vou usar para contar o placar depois
var certos = ["0", "7", "10", "14", "17"];

function allfalse(obj) {
    // Ve se o usuario respondeu a questão "obj"
    for (var k in obj) {
        if (obj[k]) {  //Se for true vai entrar aqui
            return true; //Se ele\a respondeu a questão entra aqui e para o loop
        }
    }
    return false; //Se nenhuma das opções da pergunta foi escolhida vai cair aqui

}

function alltrue(lis) {
    // Faz o contrario que a função anterior, é para checar se todas as peguntas foram respondidas
    for (var k in lis) {
        if (!lis[k]) { 
        // Se tiver alguma questão não respondida(false na função anterior) vai cair aqui
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true; // Se todas foram respondidas vai cair aqui

}

function check() {
//Essas variaveis veêm todas opçoes de cada questão separadamente, e checam se foi escolhido ou não
    var q1 = [document.getElementById("0").checked, document.getElementById("1").checked, document.getElementById("2").checked, document.getElementById("3").checked];
    var q2 = [document.getElementById("4").checked, document.getElementById("5").checked, document.getElementById("6").checked, document.getElementById("7").checked];
    var q3 = [document.getElementById("8").checked, document.getElementById("9").checked, document.getElementById("10").checked, document.getElementById("11").checked];
    var q4 = [document.getElementById("12").checked, document.getElementById("13").checked, document.getElementById("14").checked, document.getElementById("15").checked];
    var q5 = [document.getElementById("16").checked, document.getElementById("17").checked, document.getElementById("18").checked, document.getElementById("19").checked];
    console.log(q1, q2, q3, q4, q5);
    var todas = [allfalse(q1), allfalse(q2), allfalse(q3), allfalse(q4), allfalse(q5)];
    // var todas, joga a lista de cada uma das questões para a função allfalse 
    console.log(todas);
    console.log(alltrue(todas));
    return alltrue(todas); 
    // retorna True se todas as perguntas foram respondidas e false se estiver faltando

}

function placar() {
    var placar = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < 19; i++) {
        //checa todas opções possíveis
        if (document.getElementById(i.toString()).checked){ 
            //Se a opção estiver selecionada entra aqui 
            if (certos.includes(i.toString()))  { 
                /* Se a opção selecionada estiver na lista de certos entra aqui e aumenta o placar
                para usar esse método eu coloquei o id de todas opções como se fossem index de uma lista
                */
                placar += 1;                  
            }
        }
    }
    return placar;
}


function mostrar_placar() {
    if (!check()) {
        //Se check deu false vai alertar o usuário para responder todas questões
        alert("Todas as questões são obrigatórias");
    } else {
        //Se não tiver erro irá mostrar o placar
        alert("Seu placar é " + placar());
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML5>
<html>
    <head lang=pt>
       <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Formulario</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="quiz1.css">
        <script src=quiz.js></script>
    </head>    
    <body>        
            <form class=formulario onsubmit="return mostrar_placar()"> 
                <h3>Qual é o nome do inventor da linguagem de programação Python?</h3>
                <input name= "q1" id ="0" type="radio" value="Guido van Rossum">Guido van Rossum<br> 
                <input name= "q1" id ="1" type="radio" value="Dennis Ritchie">Dennis Ritchie<br> 
                <input name= "q1" id ="2" type="radio" value="James Gosling">James Gosling<br>
                <input name= "q1" id ="3" type="radio" value="Brendan Eich">Brendan Eich<br>           
                <h3>Dentre as alternativas a seguir, qual não é um item de hardware?</h3>
                <input name= "q2" id ="4" type="radio" value="Mouse">Mouse<br> 
                <input name= "q2" id ="5" type="radio" value="Processador">Processador<br> 
                <input name= "q2" id ="6" type="radio" value="Chipset">Chipset<br>
                <input name= "q2" id ="7" type="radio" value="Debian">Debian<br><br>
                <h3>O que é Windows da Microsoft?</h3>
                <input name= "q3" id ="8" type="radio" value="Processador">É um processador<br> 
                <input name= "q3" id ="9" type="radio" value="Navegador">É um navegador<br> 
                <input name= "q3" id ="10" type="radio" value="SO">É um sistema operacional<br>
                <input name= "q3" id ="11" type="radio" value="Antivirus">É um antivírus<br><br> 
                <h3>Qual da alternativas contêm somente sistemas operacionais?</h3>
                <input name= "q4" id ="12" type="radio" value="Asus">Asus, AMD, Intel.<br> 
                <input name= "q4" id ="13" type="radio" value="Word">Word, Excel, Powerpoint<br> 
                <input name= "q4" id ="14" type="radio" value="Windows">Windows 8, Android, IOS<br>
                <input name= "q4" id ="15" type="radio" value="Mozila">Mozila Firefox, Internet Explorer, Google Chrome.<br><br>                 
                <h3>Qual a principal função do Sistema Operacional?</h3>
                <input name= "q5" id ="16" type="radio" value="Correcao">Corrigir os danos de um Computador.<br> 
                <input name= "q5" id ="17" type="radio" value="Conexão">Servir de intermediário entre o usuário e os componentes do computador<br> 
                <input name= "q5" id ="18" type="radio" value="Internet">Estabelecer conexão com a Internet.<br>
                <input name= "q5" id ="19" type="radio" value="Debian">Processar dados<br><br>                
                <input type="submit" value="confirmar">
        </form>   
        
        
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Form validation

One option to simplify the code that validates the form field selections is to utilize the HTML5 feature [form data validation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Form_validation). Basically, adding the [required](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attr-required) attribute to all radio buttons (well, at least one per group - see [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8287947/1575353) for more context)
should suffice. With that, the form submit callback function (i.e. `mostrar_placar()` can be simplified to merely calling `placar()` in the line that shows the alert.

#### Cache DOM references

DOM lookups (e.g. `document.getElementById()`) are expensive, and should only happen once per element or set of elements. It is wise to store those in an variable (or constant if you want to use the es6 [const](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const)).

#### Checking number of correct answers

Instead of having the function `placar()` loop through all inputs, just to see if each is checked and if so, if the `id` attribute is included in `certos`, the function could simply iterate over the correct answers and check if the associated input is checked. For a small application like this, the difference between 20 iterations and 5 is small, but it would be a big difference in a larger application.

#### Alerts

As [Blindman67](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/120556/blindman67) advised [in a comment](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/120556/blindman67) on [Tushar's answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/189640/120114):

> Be aware that alerts can be disabled and should not be used to provided user feedback as you can not know (without some extra code and guess work) if it has been read. It is far better to provide feedback on the page.

So it might be wise to create an element and have that element appear/update when appropriate, instead of using `alert()`.

### Rewrite

See the code below, which takes into consideration the recommendations above.

**UPDATE:**

Apparently using the `required` attribute is forbidden. In that case, a simpler way to ensure that all questions are completed is to use a [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) object and then get the keys with [FormData.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/keys) and because that returns an iterator, convert that to an array with [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from). Finally, return the equality of the length of that array with the array containing the correct answers.

```js
// Põe o ID das respostas certas em uma lista, vou usar para contar o placar depois
var certos = ["0", "7", "10", "14", "17"];
//declare variables here - could use keyword let instead of var
var inputs, result;
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  //when DOM is ready, access elements

  //store checkboxes in an array
  inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"]');
  result = document.getElementById('result');
});

function placar() {
  var placar = 0;
  //find the number of checked correct answers
  return certos.reduce(function(cumulativeSum, certo) {
    if (inputs[certo].checked) {
      cumulativeSum++;
    }
    return cumulativeSum;
  }, 0);
}

function check() {
  //create FormData object- could also give the <form> an id and 
  // access it via document.getElementById()
  var fd = new FormData(document.forms[0]);
  //check that the number of completed questions is the same as the number of correct answers
  return Array.from(fd.keys()).length ==  certos.length;
}


function mostrar_placar() {
  if (!check()) {
        //Se check deu false vai alertar o usuário para responder todas questões
       // alert("Todas as questões são obrigatórias");
       result.innerHTML = "Todas as questões são obrigatórias";
    } else {
        //Se não tiver erro irá mostrar o placar
       // alert("Seu placar é " + placar());   
    result.innerHTML = "Seu placar é " + placar();
  }
  return false; //stop form from submitting
}
```

```css
#result {
  border: 1px solid #f00;
}
```

```html
<form class=formulario onsubmit="return mostrar_placar()" >
  <h3>Qual é o nome do inventor da linguagem de programação Python?</h3>
  <input name="q1" id="0" type="radio" value="Guido van Rossum">Guido van Rossum<br>
  <input name="q1" id="1" type="radio" value="Dennis Ritchie">Dennis Ritchie<br>
  <input name="q1" id="2" type="radio" value="James Gosling">James Gosling<br>
  <input name="q1" id="3" type="radio" value="Brendan Eich">Brendan Eich<br>
  <h3>Dentre as alternativas a seguir, qual não é um item de hardware?</h3>
  <input name="q2" id="4" type="radio" value="Mouse">Mouse<br>
  <input name="q2" id="5" type="radio" value="Processador">Processador<br>
  <input name="q2" id="6" type="radio" value="Chipset">Chipset<br>
  <input name="q2" id="7" type="radio" value="Debian">Debian<br><br>
  <h3>O que é Windows da Microsoft?</h3>
  <input name="q3" id="8" type="radio" value="Processador">É um processador<br>
  <input name="q3" id="9" type="radio" value="Navegador">É um navegador<br>
  <input name="q3" id="10" type="radio" value="SO">É um sistema operacional<br>
  <input name="q3" id="11" type="radio" value="Antivirus">É um antivírus<br><br>
  <h3>Qual da alternativas contêm somente sistemas operacionais?</h3>
  <input name="q4" id="12" type="radio" value="Asus">Asus, AMD, Intel.<br>
  <input name="q4" id="13" type="radio" value="Word">Word, Excel, Powerpoint<br>
  <input name="q4" id="14" type="radio" value="Windows">Windows 8, Android, IOS<br>
  <input name="q4" id="15" type="radio" value="Mozila">Mozila Firefox, Internet Explorer, Google Chrome.<br><br>
  <h3>Qual a principal função do Sistema Operacional?</h3>
  <input name="q5" id="16" type="radio" value="Correcao">Corrigir os danos de um Computador.<br>
  <input name="q5" id="17" type="radio" value="Conexão">Servir de intermediário entre o usuário e os componentes do computador<br>
  <input name="q5" id="18" type="radio" value="Internet">Estabelecer conexão com a Internet.<br>
  <input name="q5" id="19" type="radio" value="Debian">Processar dados<br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="confirmar">
</form>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: I'm forbidden to use required, but the remainder of the answer is super useful, thanks a lot!

Comment: okay- I know it isn't obligatory but I updated the rewrite to not use the `required` attribute on the input elements.